# Rails + ChartKick Pie Chart Counting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

I've got a Rails app with two models and a relationship between them. I am using ChartKick to display the number of Provider Orders by Zipcode.

**order.rb Model**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :provider
belongs_to :address
```

**provider.rb Model**

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :orders

def past_orders_chart
    Order.where(:provider_id => self.id).where(:status => "2")
end
```

**address.rb model**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :orders
```

**past_orders.html.erb**

```
<%= pie_chart @past_orders_chart.includes(:address).group(:zipcode).sum(:zipcode) %>
```

[Here is how the chart looks using 'sum':](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg5ve.png)

The problem is it is summing the zipcodes which makes sense based on the above command.

If I change the command to 'count' instead of 'sum', it displays the graph but only counts the unique occurrences of the zipcode.

```
 pie_chart  =@past_orders_chart.includes(:address).group(:zipcode).count(:zipcode)
```

[Here is how the chart looks using 'count':](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psNRn.png)

Using 'sum' produces the correct pie chart visually (in terms of percentages shown in the chart.

So the question is how can I get the chart to list the total number of times the zipcode appears in the dataset? *I tried to post a third example screenshot but was blocked by SO.*

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved this to the model and was able to solve it with the following:

```
def past_orders_chart

    Order.where(:provider_id => self.id).where(:status => "2").joins(:address).group(:zipcode).count

end
```

Then call the method from the controller as @past_orders_chart and pass it to the view:

```
 <%= pie_chart @past_orders_chart, :library => {is3D: true } %>
```

Answer (score -1):

To debug that issue, you should run both in the `rails console` and/or use .to_sql to see what's the query that is being run.

This is not a charts/chartkick issue as you tagged.

Using `count` is adding the following to your SELECT clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT zipcode) AS count_zipcode_id
```

So, if you don't it to count distinct value of zipcode, you should replace it by

```
@past_orders_chart.includes(:address).group(:zipcode).select('COUNT(*) AS count_zipcode_id')
```